# How to segment exported UV textures to be different colors?

Tags: modeling, uv

I was wondering if there was a way to export unwrapped UV island to be its own color from the model itself, [image]

something like this, where certain faces of the mesh can be of a certain color and that can be exported?

Comment: You can assign a different material to those faces, or use a texture to create a map. In your example, you could use the individual RGB channel. The only way to export colors though ist through vertex colors, since complex things like masks will likely not export to other programs

Comment: how did u mean for the vertex colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use screenshots, so I can't comment, please don't downvote if it doesn't solver your problem entirely.
Use CTRL+ TAB to switch between modes

1. Go into edit mode and select all faces that are supposed to have the same color

[image]
2. enable paint mask option

[image]

3. Select your color and go to paint -> set color, or press SHIFT K
   However you need to make sure whatever program you are importing with supports vertex colors. Unity for example does, but you need to find a shader that reads them.